# Pyodide - Python async unit tests

Tags: javascript, python, pyodide

I'm trying to implement async unit tests running with usage of pyodide library. Synchronous tests work just fine, I have a problem with async tests.
I created a class definition where I'm placing all tests something like

```
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase

class TestClass(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):

    async def test_case_one(self):
        print('hello')
        result = await functionality()
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

I have to run it through runner which is working fine for synchronous code but I have an error running it with async code:

```
import unittest
from pprint import pprint

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
result = runner.run(unittest.makeSuite(TestClass))
```

after execution of this code I'm receiving this error:
[image]

Everything is working fine if I'm not using **IsolatedAsyncioTestCase** in my TestClass but **TestCase** but this is for synchronous code.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
This is the pyodide console which I'm using: https://pyodide.org/en/latest/console.html
Thank you for response